# Get info from a view function and call it in a different function in view.py

Tags: python, django

I have a post page where you can see the post content and details like comments.  I also want a separate page containing a form where you can type out the comment, and when the submit button is clicked, post the comment in the page.  Here's what I have so far:

My post view:

```
def post_detail(request, id, slug):
   post = Post.objects.get(id = id) # I want this to be able to be called in a different function
   comments = Comment.objects.filter(post = post).order_by('-id')

   is_liked = False
   if post.likes.filter(id = request.user.id).exists():
     is_liked = True

   context = {
       'post' : post,
       'is_liked' : is_liked,
       'get_likes' : post.get_likes(),
       'total_likes' : post.total_likes(),
       'comments' : comments,
   }
   return render(request, 'post_detail.html', context)
```

My url for post view: `url(r'(?P\d+)/(?P[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name = "post_detail"),

Here's the post_detail.html:

```
<body>
<h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
<small>Post created by: {{ post.author }}</small>

<p>{{post.body|safe}}</p>
{% include 'like_post.html' %}

<div class= "main-comment-section">
    {{comments.count}} Comment{{comments|pluralize}}
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <p class= "mb-0">{{comment.content}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <a href = "{% url 'add_comment' %}" class = "btn btn-secondary">Add comment</a>
</div>
```

My comment form view:

```
def add_comment(request, id):
   post = Post.objects.get(id = id)

   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = CommentForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit = False)
        comment.save()
        return redirect('posts')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

context = {
    'comment_form' : comment_form
}
return render(request, 'add_comment.html', context)
```

How can I write the views.py function and urls so that when I click "add answer" in post_detail.html, I can get the page with the comment form to show up and post it properly?

Comment: Why you want a different page to add comment it can be done on same post detail page itself? i mean is there any special requirement to do so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are some updates you need to do in your code to get this working:

**Changes in urls.py:**

update url in urls.py for post_detail view (remove slug from there too)

old one:

```
url(r'(?P\d+)/(?P[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name = "post_detail"),
```

Update as:

```
url(r'^postdetail/(?P\d+)/$', post_detail, name = "post_detail"),
```

Add one more path for addcomment view in urls.py :

```
url(r'^addcomment/(?P\d+)/$', add_comment, name = "add_comment"),
```

**post_detail.html:**

In post_detail.html page pass post.id as argument to add_comment view :

old one:

```
<a href = "{% url 'add_comment' %}" class = "btn btn-secondary">Add comment</a>
```

Update as:

```
<a href = "{% url 'add_comment' id=post.id%}" class = "btn btn-secondary">Add comment</a>
```

**View.py:**

In add_comment view use redirect with reverse to post_detail instead of posts(this name doesn't exist) with id argument.

```
def add_comment(request, id):
   post = Post.objects.get(id = id)
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = CommentForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.post = post # assign post to new comment before saving else integrity error will be raised
        comment = form.save(commit = False)
        comment.save()
        return redirect(reverse("post_detail", kwargs={
                'id': post.pk
            }))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

context = {
    'comment_form' : comment_form
}
return render(request, 'add_comment.html', context)
```

**Remove slug as it is not being used from post_detail view**

old one:

```
def post_detail(request, id, slug):
```

update as:

```
def post_detail(request, id):
```